# How do you access pass protected pastebin with python?

Tags: python

Im trying to run a python script from a pastebin link but I wanna have the pastebin be password protected this is all I got

```
import requests

pastebin_raw_link = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/F4adqxBq'
response = requests.get(pastebin_raw_link)
source_code = response.content

exec(source_code.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I know, it is my page its currently just a BSOD troll script I used for testing

Answer (score 1):

You can use developer's api to access private pastes as mentioned [here](https://pastebin.com/doc_api#13):

```
curl -X POST -d 'api_dev_key=YOUR API DEVELOPER KEY' -d 'api_user_key=YOUR API USER KEY' -d 'api_option=show_paste' -d 'api_paste_key=API PASTE KEY' "https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php"
```

The above is a sample POST request which you need to perform using python with the following parameters:

1. `api_dev_key` - this is your API Developer Key, which [you can obtain by logging into the pastebin](https://pastebin.com/doc_api#1)
2. `api_user_key` - this is the session key of the logged in user
3. `api_paste_key` - this is paste key you want to fetch the data from.
4. `api_option` - set as 'show_paste' (No need to change)

Now you can get all the above except the `api_user_key` session key. To get session key you need to call another API before this API as mentioned [here](https://pastebin.com/doc_api#9). The following is the sample POST request which you need to convert into python:

```
curl -X POST -d 'api_dev_key=YOUR API DEVELOPER KEY' -d 'api_user_name=a_users_username' -d 'api_user_password=a_users_password' "https://pastebin.com/api/api_login.php"
```

with the parameters:

1. `api_dev_key` - this is your API Developer Key
2. `api_user_name` - this is the username of the user you want to login.
3. `api_user_password` - this is the password of the user you want to login.